# Finding real numbers so that 3 vectors are orthogonal to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $u=(a,b,c)$ transpose with a and c not equal to 0. Find real numbers x and y such that the vector $v = (b, -a, x)^T$ is orthogonal to $u$, and the vector  $w = (a,b,y)^T$ is orthogonal to both $u$ and $w$.

My steps:

$$(a,b,c)^T\cdot (b,-a,x)^T = 0$$

So, $ab - ab + cx = 0$, $cx = 0$ and knowing that c is not equal to zero, $x = 0$

Then,

$$(a,b,c)^T\cdot (a,b,y)^T = 0$$

So, $a^2+b^2+cy=0$ and knowing that a is not equal to zero means that $(a^2+b^2)>0$, therefore either $c>0$ and $y<0$ or $c<0$ and $y>0$

And finally,

$$(b,-a,x)^T \cdot (a,b,y)^T = 0$$

So, $ab - ab + xy = 0$, so $xy = 0$ which is true regardless of $y$, because $x = 0$

So essentially, I get 2 scenarios:

1. $c>0 \implies x=0$ and $y<0$
2. $c<0 \implies x=0$ and $y>0$

   However, I have a feeling this is not precise enough for the answer.

Comment: You start saying "Let u=(a,b,c)" but then say "vector w = (a,b,c) transpose is orthogonal to both u and w".  u  is identical to w.  A vector **can't** be orthogonal to itself!

Comment: I think you w should be (a,b,y), otherwise there is no y in your question. Is this a mistake?

Comment: @user247327 The zero vector is orthogonal to itself, but that’s excluded by the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there, but instead of complicating matters with inequalities, you can simply express $y$, the solution is unque:

$$a^2+b^2+cy=0\rightarrow y=-\frac{a^2+b^2}{c}$$

And the last step is still true, so this $y$ also ensures orthogonality with $v$.